# Get specific Julia method in C

Tags: julia

How can I access a method of a Julia function in Julia's C API?. There are structs `jl_method_instace_t` and `jl_method_t` which I suppose are meant to be containers for Julia methods on the C level, but how can one of them be constructed? And how can one get a specific method of an abstract function.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And _functions_ don't have _methods_.

Comment: The Julia documentation has a chapter on embedding Julia in C, i.e. calling Julia functions from C, but it has no mention of `jl_method_instance_t` nor `jl_method_t`.

Comment: There's a jl_invoke function exported in julia.h which looks like it should be used to invoke Julia methods, given an array of jl_value_t *'s. But there doesn't seem to be an interface to construct jl_method_instance_t *'s in Julia itself, from Julia generic functions (given a list of types). So I'm pretty sure he's asking how to generate jl_method_instance_t's from Julia so they can be jl_invoked on the C side. This is obviously not documented, currently, hence the question.

Comment: Might be helpful to know what your end-goal is, you might not need to use those?

Comment: It would be used to call Julia functions on Julia objects efficiently from a C interface to Julia, without going through the generic function lookup in Julia. You can push such functions down to C functions, but then you need to have a C function pointer prototype for every single Julia function you want to call. Since this is interfacing work, and there are potentially thousands of functions that could be potentially involved, one wants to do it more generically than that, but still efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer. You can get a specific method by calling the "which" function.

```
julia> f = which(+, (Int, Int))
+{T<:Union{Int128,Int16,Int32,Int64,Int8,UInt128,UInt16,UInt32,UInt64,UInt8}}(x::T, y::T) at int.jl:32

julia> typeof(f)
Method
```

I don't know how to "unbox" (not sure of the terminology), the corresponding jl_value_t * for f on the C side to get a jl_method_t *. But I think this gets you half way there.

I suspect this is the best you can do, since specializations seem to only exist if the function has already been called (and hence Jit compiled), for that set of arguments.

I'm not sure what a jl_method_instance_t is.

Comment: Apparently, in Julia 0.6 one can create a `jl_method_instance_t` using `jl_get_specialized`. Unfortunately, this function is not exposed in the Julia library.